# Grails - Redeploy after javascript change

Tags: javascript, grails

Recently I added conf/ApplicationResources.groovy (using resources plugin) file to my project structure. Here I keep my modules definitions for javascript and css libraries. Before, I was importing libraries with classic `g:javascript` tag.

Now every time when javascript code changes (while server is running) I get client side js error saying

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input".

So for each javascript change application needs to be redeployed, what I dont want.

I have also declared .js files to be excluded from resources plugin pattern, but the problem remains. Any advice/help will be appreciated.

---

Solution from Sérgio Michels that worked:

- Add to Config.groovy: "grails.resources.debug = true;"

Comment: I think you should use r:require tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid cache issues with the Resources plugin, in all my projects I'm using the config `grails.resources.debug = true` in Config.groovy.

You still use `<r:require modules=""/>` in your GSP, but in development mode the source will show all files included instead of merging them.